# Where to find the latest version + latest documentation of Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm implementing Paypal Express Checkout on a website, but am left a bit dubious about whether I'm using the latest API version, and the latest documentation.

The [documentation on the Paypal website](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation#ec) points to these files:

- Express Checkout
  Integration Guide: [PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf)
- Name-Value Pair API
  Developer Guide: [PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

I can tell that they do not refer to the latest API version though, as they're using fields that [this page](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoExpressCheckoutPayment) considers deprecated (`AMT`, `PAYMENTACTION`, ...)

So my questions are:

1. Where can I be sure to *always* browse the **latest** Express Checkout documentation?
2. Where to find which is the **latest** version number (`XX.0`) available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1)  X.com houses the latest documentation.  See [this page](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools) for a list.

2)  The [WSDL](http://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl) will be your best source for the latest version. ex:  ns:version="89.0" right at the top.